# How to integrate ruby in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-2010

Currently I'm started to learn Ruby in Steel 2.

I installed Ruby from [the link](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/spip?page=download) and also I installed the Interpreters from the [same link](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/spip?page=download), rubyinstaller-1.9.2-p290.exe, but while running in Visual Studio 2010 it's showing

```
**Error  :-**

'RunRuby Exception : unsupported Interpreter Type : Not Supported'
```

How do I resolve this issue? If anybody has some idea of correct interpreter for Ruby in Steel 2 please share your views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is because of wrong version of Interpreter selected by visual studio.I mean the path may be wrong or version mismatch.

You uninstall all and install Ruby in Steel setup and then ruby Interpreter from the  same link you used earlier.

And just follow this to get visual studio to select the right path of ruby installed.

Follow this link [here](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Tutorials/Ruby-In-Steel-Tutorials/archives/ruby-in-steel-1-38/article/ruby-in-steel-1-5-build)

It should work and i got the same problem and it worked for me.